# laravel passport: why the same code works with Http Get request but doesn't work with POST?

Tags: c#, laravel, oauth, rest-client, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel application and a C# application that connects to it via Passport.

I made simple functions to make the user update his password like this:

**Laravel Route**

```
Route::post('user/updatepassword','UserController@changepassword')->middleware('auth:api');
```

**Laravel Controller**

```
public function changepassword(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [ 'password' => 'required|string|max:255' ]);

    $newuser = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $newuser->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $newuser->save();
}
```

**C# Function**

```
public string UpdatePassword(string password)
{
    var client = new RestClient(APPConnection.ApiRoot + "user/updatepassword");
    //// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

    var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("password", password); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Current_User.access_token);

    // execute the request
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

    return content;
}
```

This code doesn't work, and it throws a lot of exceptions that are meaningless, or, at least, I can't figure it out. 
However, when I change everything to use HTTP GET requests on both the C# code and Laravel end, it works fine.

I'm not sure what is wrong. It may be that the way I'm passing the token should be different for the GET and the POST request.

Here is a copy of the response I get:

> ```
> {
>   "message": "",
>   "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
>   "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
>   "line": 203,
>   "trace": [
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
>       "line": 175,
>       "function": "prepareException",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplication\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
>       "line": 51,
>       "function": "render",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 83,
>       "function": "render",
>       "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 55,
>       "function": "handleException",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
>       "line": 49,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
>       "line": 63,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
>       "line": 37,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php",
>       "line": 59,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 102,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
>       "line": 647,
>       "function": "then",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
>       "line": 622,
>       "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
>       "line": 588,
>       "function": "runRoute",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
>       "line": 577,
>       "function": "dispatchToRoute",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
>       "line": 176,
>       "function": "dispatch",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 30,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
>       "line": 56,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
>       "line": 30,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
>       "line": 30,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
>       "line": 27,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
>       "line": 46,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 149,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 53,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
>       "line": 102,
>       "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
>       "line": 151,
>       "function": "then",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplicationendor\\laravel\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
>       "line": 116,
>       "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
>       "type": "->"
>     },
>     {
>       "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myefapplication\\public\\index.php",
>       "line": 55,
>       "function": "handle",
>       "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
>       "type": "->"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Though you didn't show the error you're getting, I'm guessing it is a CSRF error. POST routes are protected by CSRF by default in Laravel, so you either need to pass in a valid CSRF token, or exempt the update password route from CSRF protection (not recommended).

Comment: try this `Route::post('/user/updatepassword','UserController@changepassword')->middleware('auth:api');`

Comment: @patricus I added the response I get from the post request. I didn't understand anything from it but you might. and I didn't read anything about the csrf in the api auth part of the laravel docs. I thought that the token is a replacement for it. and I'm not even sure how to pass it via a third party app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why your exception output is so horrible, but you're running into a CSRF token mismatch exception.

Laravel expects a CSRF token by default on all POST routes in the `web` middleware. All routes defined inside the `routes/web.php` file are placed inside the `web` middleware group.

If this is meant to be an API endpoint (which, given that you're using passport, I assume it is), your route should be defined inside the `routes/api.php` file. By doing this, it is placed in the `api` middleware group instead of the `web` middleware group. This will remove the CSRF token restriction, among other things.

Comment: I thought placing "->middleware('auth:api');" after the route would do, but it seems that it doesn't and i'm not sure why. anyway I placed the route in the api.php file and changed the post request to "APPConnection.ApiRoot + "api/user/updatepassword"" and this works, thank you.